# Android: Asynctask without showing dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask

I've searched in the web but I only find cases where the users want to show the dialog in the asynctask like this example: protected void onPreExecute().

```
{
                            super.onPreExecute();
                            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NumericoComercial.this);
                            pDialog.setMessage("Actualizando ...");
                            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                            pDialog.show();
                        }
```

What I would like to know is if it can be done an asynctask without showing any dialog in onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() as usually is done.

I have experienced some problems using asynctask with dialogs regarding Window Leaked Error. The thing I've tried is not adding any dialog to the Pre and Post Actions like the following example.

```
class UpdateCandidatos extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {

                    }


protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

                    }
                }
```

Could be any errors using this method, for example when the activity is finished?

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: I've eddited it, but what I mean is that if is recommendable to use dialogs in Asynctask in order to reduce errors, or if I could not include them without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` are not required methods extending `Aynctask` then all the things you write in those methods (Dialog, ProgressDialog etc) are unnecessary for the correct working of your class.

```
class UpdateCandidatos extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) { 
        //add here your background work
    }

}
```

this is a very simplified and fully forking `AsyncTask` that do "something" in background showing no dialog.

Note: you will have to handle the task according to the lifecycle of your app

Comment: hi Roberto thanks for the explanation, I've removed those 2 methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you cancel your async task in you onPause() method. This way if your activity closes, the async task wont try to publish any data, and onPostExecute wont be called.

Hm, you shouldn't be having any errors with onPostExecute(), you can use async task without showing any data, its not mandatory. You dont even have to @override that function, just put Void i the declaration ( ...extends AsyncTask<...,...,Void> )

Comment: Then, not showing any dialog won't provoke the app to crash, right?

Comment: Thats right. But still i dont forget to cancel your AsyncTask when closing your activity, since onPostExecute is executed in the UI thread and even though you wont be doing any UI modification it can cause the app to misbehave since you can never know for sure what will go on in the background.